# Any way of getting more info from c++filt demangled output

Tags: c++, templates, ostream, c++filt

I just ran `c++filt` to demangle when I had a duplicate symbol error:

```
$ c++filt __ZN4uiuclsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEERKNS_5StackE

uiuc::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, uiuc::Stack const&)
```

but the actual function looks like this [within the `uiuc` namespace]:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Stack & stack)
```

How can I get the demangled output to

1. show the return type: `std::ostream &`
2. show `std::ostream` instead of
   `std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&`. There is the `__` right after `std::` that I don't get and the template-like input. Is ostream implemented as a template?

I ask because there are other return turn types that I won't be able to easily map. I am dealing with a small file for practice.

I am running on `macOS` and tried the different `c++filt` `--format` options for the compiler but didn't see any that gave me a different output.

Comment: "Is ostream implemented as a template?" `std::ostream` is just an alias for a specialization of a class template.

Comment: @L.F., what do you mean by "specialization"?

Comment: `std::ostream` is a type alias for exactly that type. You can't demangle to a type alias; that name has been lost.

Comment: @heretoinfinity `std::vector` is a *template*, `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<double>` are *specializations* of the template. That is what is meant with *specialization*. `std::ostream` is an alias for `std::basic_ostream<char>`, a specialization of the class template `std::basic_ostream`.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. show the return type: `std::ostream &`

Return types of ordinary functions are not part of their signature or their mangled name. There is no way to obtain the return type from a mangled name. To do this you need to lookup the header file which declares the function.

This is different for function templates, though.

> 2. show `std::ostream` instead of `std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&`. There is the `__` right after `std::` that I don't get and the template-like input. Is `ostream` implemented as a template?

The standard defines that `std::ostream` is a type alias for `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>`, which is a template specialization of the class template `std::basic_ostream`. There are specializations of this for every character type that the stream could use, e.g. `std::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>>` (aliased as `std::wostream`) for wide character streams.

Type aliases are resolved during compilation to the actual type name they refer to, so the mangled name does not contain any information about the alias that was used in the declaration. It would also make no sense to have a differentiation, because the function should be the same, no matter what alias was used, so the symbol name cannot differ on it.

You could in principle run a search-and-replace for the standard library's common aliases. I don't know any tool that does that at the top of my head. You get used to the non-alias names quickly anyway.

`::__1` is an inline namespace used by the standard library to be able to define multiple versions of standard library symbols transparently. Names in the inline namespace can be looked up as if they were declared in the enclosing namespace, so when you use e.g. `std::ostream`, the library may actually declare `ostream` not in the `std` namespace, but in `std::__1`, which will still be found if `__1` is an inline namespace.

This is an implementation detail that you should simply ignore. The double underscore in the name is a good indicator that it is an implementation detail that you don't need to care about, because identifiers with a double underscore are reserved for use by the language implementation.

Again, you could probably search-and-replace such inline namespaces from the standard library namespace, but I am not aware whether any tool does that and again, one gets used to it quickly.

Comment: I declared this function as a friend function. Any way of knowing that too? When you say inline namespace, you are not referring to `inline` functions in header files?

Comment: @heretoinfinity No, whether a function is defined as `friend` inside a class is also not contained in the symbol name. And no, I don't mean `inline` functions, I mean [`inline` namespaces](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Inline_namespaces). They both use the same `inline` keyword, but the concept is completely different. The only information in the symbol name is the information that uniquely identifies the function and whether or not a function is a `friend` is not part of that. For all other information you must parse the (header) file that declares the function.